# How to get current time in Datetime format PHP?

Tags: php

I need to get current time in UTC to store in in datetime field(2019-08-17 00:00:00) type in MySQL.

How to get it in PHP?

I tried: `now();` it gives me milliseconds

Comment: Sure, before asking I googled, it says to use date()

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php

Comment: `<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$date->setTimestamp(1171502725);
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043719/php-datetimeformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find info about the DateTime class to work with dates in php

```
$d = new DateTime('now');
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: It gives me zero hours, minutes: 2019-08-17 00:00:00

Comment: try it again, I forgot ' .  `echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
This should work if the version of php you are using supports DateTime

Comment: FYI, `'now`' is the default and you can also pass the time zone as second argument ([ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)).

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Output will be : 2019-08-16 09:41:24
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$date=date_create(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
#output : 2019-08-16 09:49:20
```

Comment: This is a really convoluted way to do it, full of redundant from/to string conversions, but most importantly, it's incorrect because it doesn't take time zone into account.